# Как посчитать количество дней между датами, если у них тип string?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как посчитать количество дней между датами, которые в dataGrid, и имеют тип string? Хочу в колонку выводить результат, пока идей нету.

Внес поправки и проект запускается, но не считает дни

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = LoadProducts();

        }
        Product product = new Product();


private List<Product> LoadProducts()
{
    DateTime madeDate = Convert.ToDateTime(product.Made);
    DateTime outDate = Convert.ToDateTime(product.Out);

    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
    products.Add(new Product()
    {
        ID = 1,
        Name = "Water",
        Made = "03/01/2019",
        Out = "05/01/2019",
        Days = (outDate - madeDate).Days.ToString()
    });
    products.Add(new Product()
    {
        ID = 2,
        Name="Cheese",
        Made="08/01/2019",
        Out="15/01/2019",
        Days = (outDate - madeDate).TotalDays.ToString()
    });
    return products;
}
    public class Product
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Made { get; set; }
            public string Out { get; set; }
            public int Days { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Вы пробовали использовать DateTime?

Comment: Была идея, эти переменные у меня есть, но дальше что делать я не знаю

Comment: Советую вам хранить даты типом DateTime. Если нужно куда-то выводить, тогда уже преобразовывайте в строку.

Comment: Картинку было лень обрезать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается довольно просто, с помощью метода `DateTime.Parse()` ([ссылка на документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2)).

```
public double GetDays(string date1, string date2)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(date1);
    DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(date2);

    return (end - start).TotalDays;
}
```

#### Примечание

В `DateTime.Parse()` можно передавать формат даты (с использованием `System.Globalization`)

*Американский формат*: `DateTime.Parse(s1, new CultureInfo("en-US", false));`

*Русский формат:* `DateTime.Parse(s2, new CultureInfo("ru-RU", false));`

#### В вашем коде

Я бы переписал класс `Product` таким образом:

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Made { get; set; }
        public string Out { get; set; }
        public int Days => Product.GetDays(Made, Out);

public static double GetDays(string date1, string date2) 
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(date1);
    DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(date2);

    return (end - start).TotalDays;
}
    }
```

Comment: В коде добавил DateTime, программа запускается, но не считает дни

Comment: @Kramer Что значит «не считает дни?». А что она считает?

Comment: @Kramer Я пересмотрел ваш код, ошибка уже в другом. Пожалуйста, создайте метод GetDays(), далее вычисляйте Days = GetDays(Made, Out)

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: "Ссылка на строку не ссылается на экземпляр String."

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, просто не обратил внимание на предложенный вами клас. Всё работает